# Is getStaticPaths necessary if I already use Link inside HTML in getStaticProps?

Tags: next.js

If I use `getStaticProps` and use the data to render a page like a table of contents, is NextJS smart enough to follow those links and call `getStaticProps` to statically render those pages statically too?

In this example `/page/[id].js` is a dynamic page.

```js
//inside: index.js

export function Page({list}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(item => <Link href={'/page/'+item.id}><a>{item.title}</a></Link>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export async getStaticProps(() => {
  var list = await fetch(...);
  return {props: list};
});
```

Or am I **required** to use `getStaticPaths` to explicitly declare all those links?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have dynamic route (like that `/page/[id].js`) with `getStaticProps` but without `getStaticPaths`.

If you could, again theoretically, have that then it would make almost no sense because every page will be the same, because you can't get this param `id` in `getStaticProps` because `getStaticProps` is called **in build time** not in runtime. So you would only be able to generate one page that way and that's it.

But other that that, yes, Next.js will handle links for dynamic page just fine, for example if you have dynamic route without `getStaticProps` then all the links will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `getStaticProps`, you also have to use `getStaticPaths` in `/page/[id]` because it's a dynamic route.

However, you do not need to explicitly return *all* paths in it. With [`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) Next.js will generate any path that wasn't returned in `getStaticPaths` on-demand, and cache them for future requests.

You could have the following `getStaticPaths` function in the `/page/[id]` page.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [], // No pages will be generated at build time
        fallback: 'blocking' // Pages not generated will be on first request
    }
}
```

No pages would be generated at build time. Instead, all pages would be statically generated when the first request for that page comes in.

Comment: Why doesn't NextJs make the omission of `getStaticPaths` as implying fallback by default, instead of throwing an error when `getStaticProps` by itself without 'getStaticPaths`?

Comment: @KernelJames One to suggest to the Next.js team, I guess. There are two fallback methods available though, so you'd still need to specify which one you want.