# How to use dynamic routes without getstaticpaths

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using next.js and I want to have dynamic route like `[id].tsx`. And I want to have default html and I am going to generate rest with dynamic route param in client side. But next.js is throwing error asking to include getStaticPaths -

> Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing
> for

Comment: If you're using `getStaticProps` you also need to have `getStaticPaths` for dynamic pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is getStaticPaths necessary if I already use Link inside HTML in getStaticProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698576/is-getstaticpaths-necessary-if-i-already-use-link-inside-html-in-getstaticprops)?

Comment: But I want to have simple html to be generated at build time mainly for having i18 routing and messages to be inserted to html. I am using this route for showing orders of customers if I set fallback: "blocking" and generate new page every time someone visits their order, I think this would fill up server pretty quickly and uses unnecessary processing power. I just want to generate data in client side on top of simple html template generated on build time

Comment: In this case, you have to use query params... /my-page?value=key
this is why I find next js bad when dealing with profile stuff, i.e data that's visible only for a specific user

Answer (score 1):

There is a new way you can do this, using middlewares.

```
pages/
  some-root/
    _middleware.ts
    index.ts
```

Where the middleware file looks like:

```
export const middleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  const [, myParam] = request.nextUrl.pathname.split('/some-root/')

  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/some-root?myParam=${myParam}`, request.url))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. getServerSideProps
2. getStaticProps + query parameters
3. Don't use next.js. For SEO optimization, prerender pages