# How to use data picked from GetStaticProps, globally in NextJS/apollo/graphql?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As the title says, I want to use data from GetStaticProps in another file, in another component. Can not use GetStaticProps in the component because :

> Server Error
> Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/[title]'.

Basically, I want to use data gathered from GetStaticProps in nextjs dynamic route file.
Tried to fix it by myself for several hours, researched but couldn't find a fix. I need help, any suggestions?

Below you will find code from both files and also the picture of my file structure.

[Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YytrS.png)

> index.js:

```
import s from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import client from '../client/apollo-client';
import Postcard from '../components/Postcard';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export default function Home({ cards, WelcomeText, categories }) {

  // Store data in state
  let [data, setData] = useState(cards)


  // Filter start ======================================

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  // Filter end ========================================

  return (
    <div className={s.mainContainer}>
     
      <Logo/>
      <p className={s.welcomeText}>{WelcomeText.attributes.Text}</p>

      {/* Filter search start =========================== */}
      <div className={s.filterContainer}>
        <div className={s.searchContainer}>
          <p>
            <input className={s.searchFilther} type="text" placeholder="Search for topic..." onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}} />
          </p>  
          
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Filter search end =========================== */}

      <div className={s.contentContainer}>
        
        <div className={s.contentLeftColumn}>
        </div>

        <div className={s.contentRightColumn}>        
          {/* Cycle and filther through Postcards ===== Start*/}
          {data.filter((value)=>{
            if(searchTerm == ""){
              return value
            } else if (
              value.attributes.Title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
              return value
            } else if (
              value.attributes.Category_keywords.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
              return value
            }
          }).map((card) => (
            <div  key={card.id} className={s.cardContainer}>
              <Postcard
                className={s.postCardContainer}
                clue={card.id}
                title={card.attributes.Title}
                duration={card.attributes.Duration}
                updateDate={card.attributes.updatedAt}
                description={card.attributes.Description}
                guide={card.attributes.UniqueLink === null ? `${card.attributes.Title}` :`${cards.attributes.UniqueLink}` }
                categories={card.attributes.categories.data.map((category)=>(
                            category.attributes.Category+" "))
                }
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          {/* Cycle and filther through Postcards ===== End*/}
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

// graphql request for Postcards
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query PostCards{
      postCards(pagination: { start: 0, limit: 1000 }){
        meta{
          pagination {
            page
            total
            pageSize
            pageCount
          }
        }
        data{
          id
          attributes{
            Title
            Duration
            publishedAt
            updatedAt
            Description
            Category_keywords
            UniqueLink{
              UniqueLink
            }
            Link{
              Link
              Target
            }
             categories{
              data{
                id
                attributes{
                  Category
                }
              }
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    categories{
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          Category
        }
      }
    }
    welcomeText{
      data{
        attributes{
          Text         
        }
      }
    }
    postContents {
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          Title
        }
      }
    }
    }
    `
  })
 

 
// data.postCards.data returns Array of Postcards
// data.welcomeText.data returns just an intro text
  return {
    props: {
      cards: data.postCards.data,
      WelcomeText: data.welcomeText.data,
      categories: data.categories.data,

      // pagination
      totalCount: data.postCards.meta.pagination.total,
      pageCount: data.postCards.meta.pagination.pageCount,
      pageSize: data.postCards.meta.pagination.pageSize,

      // post content
      content: data.postContents.data,

    }
  }
}
```

> [title].js

```
const PostContent = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
         
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default PostContent;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is getStaticPaths necessary if I already use Link inside HTML in getStaticProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698576/is-getstaticpaths-necessary-if-i-already-use-link-inside-html-in-getstaticprops)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need dynamic pages for every post based on post's title which you are fetching with `getStaticProps` in `index.js`.

You should also use `getStaticPaths` to pre-render the dynamic "titles" path list.

You can read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check it out.

Comment: I didn't check your folder structure image, make sure you create a folder called "post" or something inside your "pages" folder and then, inside "post", create your dynamic page component. Inside that dynamic page component, just fetch each post route and it's content using the above mentioned functions. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will do so and let you know the result.

Comment: This solved my problem, Thank you!